# Filtering documents in mongodb and nodejs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Data in the database is stored as given below. if I do a query like

```
const food = await Nutrition.find()
```

Then I get this in response

```
[
  {
    _id: 6035ff4778b1893fa5e8080f,
    name: 'apple',
    weight: 100,
    unit: 'gram',
    carbohydrates: 14,
    calories: 52,
    proteins: 0.3,
    fats: 0.2,
    __v: 0
  },
  {
    _id: 6036011437035541b0bd5e0a,
    name: 'banana',
    weight: 100,
    unit: 'gram',
    carbohydrates: 23,
    calories: 89,
    proteins: 11,
    fats: 0.39,
    __v: 0
  },
  {
    _id: 6036011437035541b0bd5e0b,
    name: 'melon',
    weight: 100,
    unit: 'gram',
    carbohydrates: 45,
    calories: 100,
    proteins: 11,
    fats: 0.39,
    __v: 0
  }
]
```

I have this controller in nodejs which fetch food nutrition from the database

```
const Nutrition = require('../model/nutritionalFacts')

exports.nutritionFacts = (async (req,res) =>{
    try {
        const food = await Nutrition.find()
        console.log(food);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('Error occurred',error.message);
    }
})
```

Now in request (req), req.body is coming as

```
[
  { name: 'apple', id: 0, selected: true, weight: 100, unit: 'gram' },
  { name: 'banana', id: 1, selected: true, weight: 100, unit: 'gram' }
]
```

Now I want to filter only those documents from the database whose name matches with the name coming in an array of objects from the client as mentioned above without looping, just using MongoDB query syntax. Can we do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$in` [operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) to achieve that. You need to change your find method as below

```js
var namesArr = ["banana", "melon"];
db.Nutrition.find({ "name" : { "$in": namesArr } })
```

Then the results for the sample above:

```js
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("60361058cce08c8b8ebe0509"),
        "name" : "banana",
        "weight" : 100,
        "unit" : "gram",
        "carbohydrates" : 23,
        "calories" : 89,
        "proteins" : 11,
        "fats" : 0.39,
        "__v" : 0
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("60361058cce08c8b8ebe050a"),
        "name" : "melon",
        "weight" : 100,
        "unit" : "gram",
        "carbohydrates" : 45,
        "calories" : 100,
        "proteins" : 11,
        "fats" : 0.39,
        "__v" : 0
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```js
const Nutrition = require('../model/nutritionalFacts');

exports.nutritionFacts = (async (req, res) => {
  try {

    if (!Array.isArray(req.body.payload)) {
      throw new Error("Invalid payload!") // or whatever error message u want!
    }

    const names = payload.map(item => item.name); // u cannot avoid this looping of payload!

    const conditions = {
      name: { $in: names }
    };

    const food = await Nutrition.find(conditions);
    console.log(food);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('Error occurred', error.message);
  }
})
```